# In SDL how do I find the name of an SDL_Event.type

Tags: c, sdl

I see that SDL_Event.type is a number that corresponds to a specific type of event, aside from using google for each new event I encounter, is there a way to convert them to a string with their name?

for example I couldn't find anything online on type 1024 or 0x400 and I scrolled through all the possible values of the constants and saw it was mouse movement.

Comment: [`SDL_events.c:SDL_LogEvent()`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.28.x/src/events/SDL_events.c#L162-L538); sadly not public, nor does it return a string.  But *does* contain a `switch` ladder you can steal :)

Comment: You can find the events in SDL_events.h. Why do you need it to be a string?

Comment: You can also find it in the docs: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_EventType

Answer (score 0):

A complete list of the `SDL_EventType`s can be found in [`SDL_events.h`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.28.5/include/SDL_events.h#L52-L177). With some formatting, you could get this cheat-sheet:

| `SDL_EventType` | Value | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SDL_FIRSTEVENT | 0x0000 | Unused (do not remove) |
| SDL_QUIT | 0x0100 | User-requested quit |
| SDL_APP_TERMINATING | 0x0101 | The application is being terminated by the OS Called on iOS in `applicationWillTerminate()` Called on Android in `onDestroy()` |
| SDL_APP_LOWMEMORY | 0x0102 | The application is low on memory, free memory if possible. Called on iOS in `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning()` Called on Android in `onLowMemory()` |
| SDL_APP_WILLENTERBACKGROUND | 0x0103 | The application is about to enter the background Called on iOS in `applicationWillResignActive()` Called on Android in `onPause()` |
| SDL_APP_DIDENTERBACKGROUND | 0x0104 | The application did enter the background and may not get CPU for some time Called on iOS in `applicationDidEnterBackground()` Called on Android in `onPause()` |
| SDL_APP_WILLENTERFOREGROUND | 0x0105 | The application is about to enter the foreground Called on iOS in `applicationWillEnterForeground()` Called on Android in `onResume()` |
| SDL_APP_DIDENTERFOREGROUND | 0x0106 | The application is now interactive Called on iOS in `applicationDidBecomeActive()` Called on Android in `onResume()` |
| SDL_LOCALECHANGED | 0x0107 | The user's locale preferences have changed. |
| SDL_DISPLAYEVENT | 0x0150 | Display state change |
| SDL_WINDOWEVENT | 0x0200 | Window state change |
| SDL_SYSWMEVENT | 0x0201 | System specific event |
| SDL_KEYDOWN | 0x0300 | Key pressed |
| SDL_KEYUP | 0x0301 | Key released |
| SDL_TEXTEDITING | 0x0302 | Keyboard text editing (composition) |
| SDL_TEXTINPUT | 0x0303 | Keyboard text input |
| SDL_KEYMAPCHANGED | 0x0304 | Keymap changed due to a system event such as an input language or keyboard layout change |
| SDL_TEXTEDITING_EXT | 0x0305 | Extended keyboard text editing (composition) |
| SDL_MOUSEMOTION | 0x0400 | Mouse moved |
| SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN | 0x0401 | Mouse button pressed |
| SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP | 0x0402 | Mouse button released |
| SDL_MOUSEWHEEL | 0x0403 | Mouse wheel motion |
| SDL_JOYAXISMOTION | 0x0600 | Joystick axis motion |
| SDL_JOYBALLMOTION | 0x0601 | Joystick trackball motion |
| SDL_JOYHATMOTION | 0x0602 | Joystick hat position change |
| SDL_JOYBUTTONDOWN | 0x0603 | Joystick button pressed |
| SDL_JOYBUTTONUP | 0x0604 | Joystick button released |
| SDL_JOYDEVICEADDED | 0x0605 | A new joystick has been inserted into the system |
| SDL_JOYDEVICEREMOVED | 0x0606 | An opened joystick has been removed |
| SDL_JOYBATTERYUPDATED | 0x0607 | Joystick battery level change |
| SDL_CONTROLLERAXISMOTION | 0x0650 | Game controller axis motion |
| SDL_CONTROLLERBUTTONDOWN | 0x0651 | Game controller button pressed |
| SDL_CONTROLLERBUTTONUP | 0x0652 | Game controller button released |
| SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEADDED | 0x0653 | A new Game controller has been inserted into the system |
| SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEREMOVED | 0x0654 | An opened Game controller has been removed |
| SDL_CONTROLLERDEVICEREMAPPED | 0x0655 | The controller mapping was updated |
| SDL_CONTROLLERTOUCHPADDOWN | 0x0656 | Game controller touchpad was touched |
| SDL_CONTROLLERTOUCHPADMOTION | 0x0657 | Game controller touchpad finger was moved |
| SDL_CONTROLLERTOUCHPADUP | 0x0658 | Game controller touchpad finger was lifted |
| SDL_CONTROLLERSENSORUPDATE | 0x0659 | Game controller sensor was updated |
| SDL_FINGERDOWN | 0x0700 |  |
| SDL_FINGERUP | 0x0701 |  |
| SDL_FINGERMOTION | 0x0702 |  |
| SDL_DOLLARGESTURE | 0x0800 |  |
| SDL_DOLLARRECORD | 0x0801 |  |
| SDL_MULTIGESTURE | 0x0802 |  |
| SDL_CLIPBOARDUPDATE | 0x0900 | The clipboard or primary selection changed |
| SDL_DROPFILE | 0x1000 | The system requests a file open |
| SDL_DROPTEXT | 0x1001 | text/plain drag-and-drop event |
| SDL_DROPBEGIN | 0x1002 | A new set of drops is beginning (NULL filename) |
| SDL_DROPCOMPLETE | 0x1003 | Current set of drops is now complete (NULL filename) |
| SDL_AUDIODEVICEADDED | 0x1100 | A new audio device is available |
| SDL_AUDIODEVICEREMOVED | 0x1101 | An audio device has been removed |
| SDL_SENSORUPDATE | 0x1200 | A sensor was updated |
| SDL_RENDER_TARGETS_RESET | 0x2000 | The render targets have been reset and their contents need to be updated |
| SDL_RENDER_DEVICE_RESET | 0x2001 | The device has been reset and all textures need to be recreated |
| SDL_POLLSENTINEL | 0x7F00 | Signals the end of an event poll cycle |
| SDL_USEREVENT | 0x8000 | Events `SDL_USEREVENT` through `SDL_LASTEVENT` are for your use, and should be allocated with `SDL_RegisterEvents()` |
| SDL_LASTEVENT | 0xFFFF | This last event is only for bounding internal arrays |